# Need help converting google sheet to pandas dataframe, without google API or public viewing setting

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

So I'm able to use the googlesheets4 package in R to read a google sheet, but I'm unable to use pandas.read_csv(url) to read a google sheet. Using read_csv returns HTML(which seems to be because it's redirecting to an authorization page), when I set the google sheet to public, read_csv works.

This is for work, and the sheets are set to anyone in organization and view with link.

Anyone able to help?

My thought is that if a package in R can do it, that there must be a way in Python as well.

Comment: Are you looking for [tag:gspread]?

Comment: Question is not formatted correctly.